# WSFAM and SAM in one http module

Tags: wif, httpmodule, ws-federation

Why have been WSFAM and SAM http modules decoupled.
Isn't it more performant to have only one http module that intercepts HTTP calls and process further depend on a WS-FED and WIF configuration ?

Answer (score 2):

Because they can be used independently. And no - i don't see a performance issue with that.